# Why can't a tuple be a key for a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, tuples

Why can't I do the below thing :

```
a = (1,2,3)
dict[a] = 'hi'

TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be.  The problem is you're trying to access an item in the `dict` type itself.

```
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> d = {}
>>> d[a] = "hi"
>>> d
{(1, 2, 3): 'hi'}
```

As @mgilson put it in a comment: "Tuples can be hashed as long as all of their elements can be hashed."

(Note that you should never name your dictionaries `dict`, or lists `list`, etc.  This shadows the built-in name, and they're often handy to have around, e.g. `dict(zip(keys, values))`.)

Comment: @user3062488: no need to feel that way-- you learn by trying things and then seeing how they fail. :^)  But the more important lesson is that Python error messages are pretty helpful if you take them at their word.  The message `TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment` means that you're trying to assign on an object which is a `type`, and so even without any context we could have figured out what was going on.

Comment: Thanks. I will make sure to read them once atleast from now :)

Answer (score 5):

You *can* use a tuple as a key (as long as all of its items are hashable):

```
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> b = {a:'hi'}
>>> b[(1,2,3)]
'hi'
>>>
```

Your problem is that you are trying to index the built-in function [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> dict
<type 'dict'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

`dict` is a type. You want to make an instance of that type.

```
d = {}
a = (1, 2, 3)
d[a] = 'hi'
```